# Why my vue Leave transition not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I am using vee validate for form validation. i am using vue transition on displaying validations errors like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" v-validate="'required'">
<transition name="slide-fade">
  <div v-show="errors.has('name')">{{ errors.first('name') }}</div>
</transition>
```

Css:

```
    .slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Now, when an error is entering the transition is working but when the error is disappearing transition is not working.
why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transition is working. You see it suddenly blank because there's no `errors.first('name')` to show anymore.

When you add some other string along `errors.first('name')`, say `Error:`, it becomes clear.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
new Vue({
  el: '#demo'
})
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  Type something and then erase. And then type again.
  <input type="text" name="name" v-validate="'required'">
  <transition name="slide-fade">
    <div v-show="errors.has('name')">Errors: {{ errors.first('name') }}</div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

## If you really must...

Consider the amount of additional code, but if you really must do it, you would have to add a **watch** to the `input`'s value and **record the first error** when it happens.

vee-validate does not provide listeners to erros, so this is as good as it currently gets. See demo below.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    name: "Erase me",
    nameError: ""
  },
  watch: {
    name() {
      // two ticks at least, because vee-validate takes one tick to validate
      Vue.nextTick().then(Vue.nextTick()).then(() => {
        if (this.errors.has('name')) { this.nameError = this.errors.first('name'); }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  Erase and error will appear. Type again and error will leave.<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" v-validate="'required'" v-model="name">
  <transition name="slide-fade">
    <div v-show="errors.has('name')">Errors: {{ nameError }}</div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: I am currently stuck in a similar issue my Vue transitions are not triggering, however, my data seems to be reactive. It would be great if you could have a look at it and share your thoughts as to where am I going wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022673/vue-transition-not-triggering-on-button-click

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda' an old topic, but I figured out a much more easier solution that will work with a minimal amount of code, for everybody who's still searching for one.

What this does, is checking for the error message every time you press a key in the input (the `@keypress` event), saves it into a variable, which is displayed alongside the actual error message in the div, using a OR, making sure that the `error.message` variable never gets `undefined`. That OR guarantees that there will be something displayed, even if the actual error (the one given by VeeValidate) isn't available, up until the animation is finished.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data() {
    return {
      error: {
        name: null,
      },
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateError() {
      const message = this.errors.first('name');

      if (message) { // check if message isn't undefined
        this.error.name = message;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  Type something and then erase. And then type again.
  <input type="text" name="name" v-validate="'required'" @keypress="updateError()"><!-- added keypress event -->
  <transition name="slide-fade">
    <div v-show="errors.has('name')">Errors: {{ errors.first('name') || error.name }}</div><!-- OR -->
  </transition>
</div>
```

And if you have multiple inputs you can do this: pass the '$event' variable in the `updateError()` function (becoming `updateError($event)`), and accept it in the declaration. Then, use `srcElement` to get the source element that started that keypress event (in our case an input), and fetch its name/class/id/whatever; depending on that, you can modify its respective variable (in our case `error.name` and `error.email`). The rest is straight forward.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data() {
    return {
      error: {
        name: null,
        email: null,
      },
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateError(e) {
      const input = e.srcElement.name;
      const message = this.errors.first(input);

      if (message) { // check if message isn't undefined
        if (input === 'name') {
          this.error.name = message;
        } else if (input === 'email') {
          this.error.email = message;
        }
      }
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  max-width: 45%;
}

.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Type a name and then erase. And then type again.
    <input type="text" name="name" v-validate="'required'" @keypress="updateError($event)">
    <!-- added keypress event -->
    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <div v-show="errors.has('name')">Errors: {{ errors.first('name') || error.name }}</div>
      <!-- OR -->
    </transition>
  </div>

  <div class="col" style="border-left: 2px solid black; padding-left: 10px">
    Type an email and then erase. And then type again.
    <input type="text" name="email" v-validate="'required'" @keypress="updateError($event)">
    <!-- added keypress event -->
    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <div v-show="errors.has('email')">Errors: {{ errors.first('email') || error.email }}</div>
      <!-- OR -->
    </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helped you!