# Vue Transition not Triggering on button click

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue JS and I am creating a thumbnail viewer wherein I'll be getting a list of images and videos as an array of objects. At first, I will be showing just 5 items and when the user clicks Top / Bottom button, I want to slide the thumbnails vertically.

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/hardikj/pen/YvvgZG) by referring some links on StackOverflow.

I am using Vue Transitions and my data seems to be reactive but somehow I can't see the smooth transition (sliding to the top / bottom by 100px) when I click on the Top and Bottom buttons.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="thumbnail-container">
            <button class="up" @click="moveTop" :disabled="currentTopIndex === 0">Top</button>
            <div :class="'slider' + (isSlidingToPrevious ? ' sliding-to-previous' : '')">
                <transition-group name='list' tag="ul">
                    <li v-for="(item,index) in currentCarouselData" v-bind:key="index" class="list-item"><img :src="item.itemImage" :alt="item.itemImageAlt" /></li>
                </transition-group>
            </div>
            <button @click="moveBottom" class="down" :disabled="currentBottomIndex === totalCount">Down</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>
    totalCount {{totalCount}}
    currentTopIndex {{currentTopIndex}}
    currentBottomIndex {{currentBottomIndex}}
    itemsToDisplay {{itemsToDisplay}}
    currentCarouselData {{currentCarouselData}}
</pre>
</div>
```

CSS / LESS Code:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  li {
    flex: 1;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
  }
}

.list-leave-active,
.list-enter-active {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.list-enter {
  transform: translate(0, 100px);
}
.list-leave-to {
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
}
.sliding-to-previous {
  .list-enter {
    transform: translate(0, -100px);
  }
  .list-leave-to {
    transform: translate(0, 100px);
  }
}
```

Javascript / VUE Code:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            totalCarouselData: [{
                    itemImage: "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
                    itemImageAlt: "Test1"
                },
                {
                    itemImage: "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
                    itemImageAlt: "Test2"
                },
                {
                    itemImage: "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
                    itemImageAlt: "Test3"
                },
                {
                    itemImage: "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
                    itemImageAlt: "Test4"
                },
                {
                    itemImage: "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
                    itemImageAlt: "Test5"
                },
                {
                    itemImage: "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
                    itemImageAlt: "Test6"
                },
                {
                    itemImage: "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
                    itemImageAlt: "Test7"
                }
            ],
            currentCarouselData: [],
            isSlidingToPrevious: false,
            totalCount: 0,
            currentTopIndex: 0,
            currentBottomIndex: 0,
            itemsToDisplay: 5
        };
    },
    computed: {},
    mounted() {
        //At first show only 5 items
        this.currentCarouselData = this.totalCarouselData.slice(
            this.currentTopIndex,
            this.itemsToDisplay
        );
        //Get Total Count
        this.totalCount = this.totalCarouselData.length;
        //Update current bottom index
        this.currentBottomIndex = this.itemsToDisplay;
    },
    methods: {
        moveTop() {
            this.isSlidingToPrevious = true;
            this.currentTopIndex += 1;
            this.currentBottomIndex -= 1;
            this.addToTopComputedArr(this.currentBottomIndex);
        },
        moveBottom() {
            this.isSlidingToPrevious = false;
            this.currentTopIndex -= 1;
            this.currentBottomIndex += 1;
            this.addToBottomComputedArr(this.currentBottomIndex);
        },
        addToBottomComputedArr(index) {
            //Splice the first item
            this.currentCarouselData.splice(0, 1);
            //Add the next item to the array
            this.currentCarouselData.push(this.totalCarouselData[index - 1]);
        },
        addToTopComputedArr(index) {
            //Splice the last item
            this.currentCarouselData.splice(index - 1, 1);
            //Add item to the beginning of the array
            this.currentCarouselData.unshift(
                this.totalCarouselData[index - this.itemsToDisplay]
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you define smooth transition

Comment: Sure.. basically it should just slide to top or bottom..

Comment: i'll give an idea of how to implement it, writing the code on SO is quite tough

Comment: I've added the Codepen link in my question if you want to give it a try :) Thanks!

Comment: what about this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzJyXJ)?

Comment: Thanks @Sphinx The pen seems to animate fine but there seems to be a glitch.. Can we tweak it in a way that when we click on Top button, all tiles move towards the top which makes the first tile disappear and the bottom tile slides from the Bottom...will I need to use .list-move class in order to do that?

Comment: Like this one https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions

Comment: probably like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzJyXJ)

Comment: @Sphinx the Top button animation is perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for..Thanks! I'm similarly trying to fix bottom...wherein the list will move up and the slide will come from bottom... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No transition issue** you met is caused by `:key="index"`.

Check [Vue Guide: key of v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key),

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with v-for, by
> default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy.
>
> This default mode is efficient, but only suitable when your list
> render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM
> state (e.g. form input values).
>
> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus
> reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key
> attribute for each item.

In your codes, your five images always have the same key=`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, so Vue will **in-place patch** them, it causes the transition is not triggered.

So simply modify the `:key="index"` to `:key="item.itemImageAlt"`, then it works.

Finally, adjust the css by yourself to make the transition effetcs meet your requirements.

**Below is one working demo:**

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      totalCarouselData: [
        {
          itemImage:
            "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
          itemImageAlt: "Test1"
        },
        {
          itemImage:
            "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
          itemImageAlt: "Test2"
        },
        {
          itemImage:
            "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
          itemImageAlt: "Test3"
        },
        {
          itemImage:
            "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
          itemImageAlt: "Test4"
        },
        {
          itemImage:
            "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
          itemImageAlt: "Test5"
        },
        {
          itemImage:
            "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
          itemImageAlt: "Test6"
        },
        {
          itemImage:
            "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg",
          itemImageAlt: "Test7"
        }
      ],
      currentCarouselData: [],
      isSlidingToPrevious: false,
      totalCount: 0,
      currentTopIndex: 0,
      currentBottomIndex: 0,
      itemsToDisplay: 5
    };
  },
  computed: {
    computedCarouseData: function () { // added computed property
        return this.totalCarouselData.slice(
        -this.currentTopIndex,
        this.itemsToDisplay-this.currentTopIndex
      )
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //At first show only 5 items
    this.currentCarouselData = this.totalCarouselData.slice(
      this.currentTopIndex,
      this.itemsToDisplay
    );
    //Get Total Count
    this.totalCount = this.totalCarouselData.length;
    //Update current bottom index
    this.currentBottomIndex = this.itemsToDisplay;
  },
  methods: {
    moveTop() {
      this.isSlidingToPrevious = true;
      this.currentTopIndex += 1;
      this.currentBottomIndex -= 1;
      this.addToTopComputedArr(this.currentBottomIndex);
    },
    moveBottom() {
      this.isSlidingToPrevious = false;
      this.currentTopIndex -= 1;
      this.currentBottomIndex += 1;
      this.addToBottomComputedArr(this.currentBottomIndex);
    },
    addToBottomComputedArr(index) {
      //Splice the first item
      this.currentCarouselData.splice(0, 1);
      //Add the next item to the array
      this.currentCarouselData.push(this.totalCarouselData[index - 1]);
    },
    addToTopComputedArr(index) {
      //Splice the last item
      this.currentCarouselData.splice(index - 1, 1);
      //Add item to the beginning of the array
      this.currentCarouselData.unshift(
        this.totalCarouselData[index - this.itemsToDisplay]
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
}
.row-eq-height ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row-eq-height li {
  flex: 1;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.row-eq-height li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.list-leave-active,
.list-enter-active {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.list-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-300px);
}
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-300px);
}
.sliding-to-previous .list-enter {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
.sliding-to-previous .list-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
.list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <button class="up" @click="moveTop" :disabled="currentTopIndex === 0">Top</button>
      <button @click="moveBottom" class="down" :disabled="currentBottomIndex === totalCount">Down</button>
      <div :class="'slider' + (isSlidingToPrevious ? ' sliding-to-previous' : '')">
        <transition-group name='list' tag="ul">
          <li v-for="(item,index) in computedCarouseData" v-bind:key="item.itemImageAlt" class="list-item"><img :src="item.itemImage" :alt="item.itemImageAlt" style=""/>{{item.itemImageAlt}}</li>
        </transition-group>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>
    totalCount {{totalCount}}
    currentTopIndex {{currentTopIndex}}
    currentBottomIndex {{currentBottomIndex}}
    itemsToDisplay {{itemsToDisplay}}
    currentCarouselData {{computedCarouseData}}
</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue ( all Reactive frameworks ) use a Virtual DOM, as you change the one of your data elements or anything visually the page gets rerendered.

Coming to your question, it is not **Smooth** because once your value is changed it gets re-rendered.

Absolute / relative position your thumbnail, once you change currentCarouselData set top as 100px. Use setInterval to decrement top till you get 0 this will bring the sliding effect

---

**EDIT transition using transition-group**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#flip-list-demo',
  data: {
    items: [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function () {
      var x = this.items.splice(0,1)[0]
      console.log(x)
      this.items.push(x)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.a-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.a-enter {
  transform: translateY(10px) 1s;
}

.a-leave {
  transform: translateY(10px) 1s;
  opacity : 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="flip-list-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <transition-group name="a" tag="ul">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item" v-show="index<5">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Comment: If you check the Vue Transitions page, they're also adding and removing the data in a similar fashion https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html 
SetInterval will always keep moving the tiles to top and bottom, I'm trying a similar approach using translateY..shouldn't it work unlike changing the top property?

Comment: No it will not work, once you change the data the page will be rerendered

Comment: But that's not the case in Vue Transitions. They're adding and removing elements in an array and it seems to animate them pretty well..

Comment: I have used it too.. <transition-group> </transition-group> I'm sorry but I can't accept your answer.. Thanks for giving a try though :)